Use CycloneDDS iceoryx shared memory with ROS2 Humble
I'm trying to use CycloneDDS shared memory feature as described in rmw_cyclonedds repo here.
However, out-of-the box I get flooded with errors like:
drv_low_in: DDS reader with topic rt/parameter_events : iceoryx subscriber - TOO_MANY_CHUNKS_HELD_IN_PARALLEL -could not take sample

After digging, it may be because of default parameters event publication that happens at start and whose history depth of 1000 exceed an hard-coded limit in iceoryx (as suggested here) (however, running demo nodes talker and listener does not show this issues... so I assume it might be partially due to the large number of nodes).
But the only config of iceoryx doable without recompiling seems to define the memory segments in the .toml config file.
So:

Do you have successful experience of shared memory with Cyclone DDS on 'large' system ? (~55 nodes including TF listener nodes)
Is there any special additional configuration I am missing ?

I'm still trying to avoid recompiling iceoryx with different hard-coded config values (looks like a hack) or to rewrite all my ROS stack to eg. disable parameter event pub/sub via NodeOptions (would break some features).
Thanks for your feedback !
